# Matplotlib subplots in nested loops

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have a python subplot question. I have a plot function that plots the data

later I am calling that function as part of a loop within another loop. I want to plot all the charts from the inner loop as subplots - 1 chart containing multiple charts for each element in outer loop. For example my outer loop has 5 values (morning, latemorning, afternoon, evening, night) and inner loop has 6 values (records, counts, avgrate, avglen, loccnt, avgduration)- right now im getting 5X6=30 charts.. but i want only 5 charts-- one for each (morning, latemorning, afternoon, evening, night) andeach of the 5 charts has 6 subplots (records, counts, avgrate, avglen, loccnt, avgduration).

here is the plot function

```
def plot(self, fname='plot_content.png', prelog=False):

    results = self.stored_vals.copy()

    if prelog:
        results = np.exp(results)

    fig= plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    colors = ['b' if c else 'r' for c in (results['used']==results['original']).values]
    ax.set_title('Number of Records')
    ax.scatter(results.index, results['original'], c=colors, lw=0, s=25., label='observed')
    results['predicted'].plot(ax=ax, color='g', label='rolling one-step out-of-sample forecast', lw=3.)
    ax.fill_between(results.index, results['low_b'], results['high_b'], alpha=.3, color='g')
    legend = ax.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.savefig(fname, format='png')
    plt.close()
```

here is where im doing the loop and calling it
for ref dayparts=(morning, latemorning, afternoon, evening, night)
df11cols=(records, counts, avgrate, avglen, loccnt, avgduration)

```
for daypart in df11['dayparts'].unique():
    df_dp = df11[df11['dayparts']==daypart]
    indexed_df = df_dp.set_index('dt')

    for measure in df11cols:

        ts = indexed_df[measure].sort_index()

        #ts = np.log(ts)

        sizeall=len(ts)
        size =sizeall- int(sizeall/4)
        train, test = ts[:size], ts[size:]

        var = OutlierDetection1D(train, arima_params=(1,1,0))

        var.run(test)
        print measure+' '+daypart
        results = var.stored_vals
        results.loc[:,'is_anomaly'] = (results['used']<>results['original'])
        colors = ['b' if c else 'r' for c in (results['used']==results['original']).values]
        results.loc[:,'colors']=colors

        print results[(~results.predicted.isnull()) & (results.colors=='r')]
        fname = 'ts_%s_%s.png'%(measure,daypart)
        #var.plot(fname, prelog=True)
        var.plot(fname)
```

Comment: I think - the problem is that you are generating a new figure in the plot function that is within the inner loop. So you are opening a new figure 5x6 times.

Comment: If you use axes instead of subplot you can place them all inside one figure with different locations. The axes constructor takes a rectangle of [lower left coordinate x, lower left corner y, height, width] and you can place that however you want in your figure, then plot your data in the axes. Make another axes in the figure, plot data in it...

Comment: Do you know how i can edit the code to accomplish this?  Thnaks!!